# Display list on several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, 3d, parallel-processing

I am trying to program display list by using parallel processing. So far the program works with no error on run time error but I can not see anything on the screen. I have a function called DisplayList. When I use it without parallel processing and calling it from the main the program works fine. But with parallel processing I can not see anything.

```
DWORD WINAPI DisplayList(LPVOID vpParam)
{
    //Some really long code that works 100%
}
```

Here is some code from the main (CPUs is the number of the cores that I got [4]):

```
GLuint* modelDL = new GLuint[totalMeshNum];
HANDLE *threads = new HANDLE[CPUs];
DWORD_PTR threadID = 0;
DWORD_PTR threadCore = 1;
int *displayListParam = new int[CPUs];
for (int i = 0; i < CPUs; i++)
{
    displayListParam[i] = (totalMeshNum / CPUs) * i;
    threadCore = 1 << i;

    threads[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, DisplayList, &displayListParam[i], 0, &threadID);
    SetThreadAffinityMask(threads[i], threadCore);
}

if (WaitForMultipleObjects(CPUs, threads, true, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
    sendErrorMessage("Error - Model Loader \nWaiting all handels failed", true);
```

And here is the drawing function:

```
void modelClass::drawModel()
{
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
glScalef(size.x, size.y, size.z);

glRotatef(angle.x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(angle.y, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(angle.z, 0, 0, 1);


glCallLists(totalMeshNum, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, modelDL);

glPopMatrix();
}
```

The DisplayList function is really long function and I have sure that the problem is not there. I have checked it several times that this function is working. I do not use any lock because I do not have any global variable. But still let me know if you need it.

The variable modelDL is fully loaded and got some data on it. So I do not understand what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you have separate, shader GL contexts? Are the actually "made current" for the relevant threads? Do you synchronize with the GL before actually using a dlist in aother thread?

Comment: For one, and probably unrelated but that doesn't matter, your program invokes *undefined behavior*. `int *displayListParam = new int[1];` I.e. an array of **one** `int`. then you proceed to write to [0..3], the last three being out of range, and thus UB. And if you're mucking with the TAM, you may want to create the threads suspended, change the TAM, then resume the threads. Just saying.

Comment: derhass - yes to all

WhozCraig - I have just noticed that and correct that. still do not working.

Comment: Each context has its own state machine, by the way. Since you are not loading an identity matrix in your `drawModel (...)` function I have to assume that your code expects the *current* matrix to be setup a particular way. But each context will have its own set of matrices. You kind of need to build the transformation into your display list(s) to do this properly. You could use an additional display list to setup the preliminary transformation state and call that display list at the beginning of `drawModel (...)`.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I suspect the fact that each context has its own matrix stack is the reason it is not working the way you want.

Comment: Well I have checked the "made current" and I did not do this well. After I did the performance did not changed. Then I understood. When one thread is "made current" the others stop. They can not work without the "made current". So the parallel processing did not help me.